# How to keep the changes done in a file in pod in kubernetes, even after the pod getting restarted?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to change a file in a pod in kubernetes but after the pod getting restarted, the file is reverting back to its original content. Is there any approach to do it? I want the updated file to be remain unchanged even after the pod getting restarted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: look into volumes or possibly configMaps

Comment: thank you, i have looked into  that but actually i don't know how to make changes in config map in running pod

Comment: POD (Containers) natively use non-persistent storage. When a container exits/terminates, so does the container’s storage so file will be recreated. 

POD (Container) can be connected to storage that is external. This will allows for the storage of persistent data if you need. Refer [Link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-volume-storage/#configure-a-volume-for-a-pod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very basic example on how to persist file content as below.

First **Create a persistent volume** refer below yaml example with hostPath configuration

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-pv-1
  lables:
    pv: my-pv-1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  hostPath:
    path: /var/log/mypath

$ kubectl create -f pv.yaml
persistentvolume/my-pv-1 created
```

Second **create a persistent volume claim** using below yaml example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc-claim-1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pv: my-pv-1


$ kubectl create -f pvc.yaml
persistentvolumeclaim/my-pvc-claim-1 created
```

**Verify the pv and pvc STATUS is  set to BOUND**

```
$ kubectl get persistentvolume
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                  STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
my-pv-1   1Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound    default/my-pvc-claim-1                         62s

$ kubectl get persistentvolumeclaims
NAME             STATUS   VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
my-pvc-claim-1   Bound    my-pv-1   1Gi        RWX                           58
```

Third **consume the pvc in required POD**(container) refer below example yaml where the volume is mounted on container.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-with-vol
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx-with-vol
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/log/mypath
      name: test-vol
  volumes:
  - name: test-vol
    persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: my-pvc-claim-1


$ kubectl create -f test-volume.yaml
pod/nginx-with-vol created


$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-with-vol   1/1     Running   0          35s   10.244.3.53   k8s-node-3   <none>           <none>
```

**Test by connecting to container** and write to the file on mount-path.

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx-with-vol -- /bin/bash
root@nginx-with-vol:/#
root@nginx-with-vol:/# df -kh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          12G  6.1G  5.5G  53% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1        12G  6.1G  5.5G  53% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/firmware
root@nginx-with-vol:/#
root@nginx-with-vol:/# cd /var/log/mypath/
root@nginx-with-vol:/var/log/mypath# pwd
/var/log/mypath
root@nginx-with-vol:/var/log/mypath# ll
bash: ll: command not found
root@nginx-with-vol:/var/log/mypath# date >> date_file.txt
root@nginx-with-vol:/var/log/mypath#
root@nginx-with-vol:/var/log/mypath# cat date_file.txt
Mon Jan 27 09:58:43 UTC 2020
root@nginx-with-vol:/var/log/mypath#
root@nginx-with-vol:/var/log/mypath# date >> date_file.txt
root@nginx-with-vol:/var/log/mypath#
root@nginx-with-vol:/var/log/mypath# cat date_file.txt
Mon Jan 27 09:58:43 UTC 2020
Mon Jan 27 09:58:51 UTC 2020
root@nginx-with-vol:/var/log/mypath#
```

Now **restart the container** and it should connect to same volume and file data should persist.

**Note : the restart count is now 1 on below example**

```
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP            NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-with-vol   1/1     Running   1          8m11s   10.244.3.53   k8s-node-3   <none>           <none>


$ kubectl exec -it nginx-with-vol -- /bin/bash
root@nginx-with-vol:/#

root@nginx-with-vol:/# cd /var/log/mypath/

root@nginx-with-vol:/var/log/mypath# ls -lart
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 27 09:58 .
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   58 Jan 27 09:58 date_file.txt
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jan 27 10:01 ..

root@nginx-with-vol:/var/log/mypath# date
Mon Jan 27 10:03:22 UTC 2020


root@nginx-with-vol:/var/log/mypath# cat date_file.txt
Mon Jan 27 09:58:43 UTC 2020
Mon Jan 27 09:58:51 UTC 2020
```

Comment: Thank you sir, for this explanation.